# Video background script with callback functions

Tags: jquery, html, video, callback

I'm looking for a plugin (might be a jquery combined with html5) that plays video in background and contains options like an event when video ends. Do you know any responsible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've found a solution to this problem. Well, there is a script

http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/

which allows to play a video in background and it's "built on top of [Video.js](http://videojs.com/)". That's why you can use an API (http://videojs.com/docs/api/). This API includes whole list of event types and contains an "ended" event.